# Desktop icon rename text color in Radiance 13.10

Tags: themes, 13.10, radiance

A little change in the Radiance theme from 13.04 to 13.10 is bugging me.  If you have an icon on the Desktop and do right click -> Rename and then click on the text, the text changed to black and the background changed to white in 13.04, but now in 13.10 the background changes to transparent.  Unfortunately, that is not good if the desktop is a dark colour.  I've been playing with modifying Radiance to be a bit more boring (more blue-gray rather than orange) but I can't find the setting that controls this behaviour in the css files under gtk-3.0.  Anyone know what it is?

I've looked at the GTK+ 3 Reference Manual but I can't find it since I don't know enough about the names of the individual widgets, et al, to work through it to my specific item.

Comment: If you're sure this isn't caused by a modification you've made, I suggest also reporting a bug against the `light-themes` package so it can be fixed in future releases.

Comment: It's not something I've done, since that's how the unmodified Radiance theme works.  It's not really a bug, but a design choice that doesn't work for me.  However, I will file a bug report in case the developers can give me a hint where the entry in the css files is.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug that was not fixed in 13.10 dev even though there was more than ample time, 3+ months from when I reported. So atm you need to live with or try to fix in source. Note it affects both ambiance & radiance themes

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1200870

Comment: I'm willing to try and fix it in the source, but it's locating the value that needs changing that's a problem.  Is it in one of the css files under gtk-3.0 or gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css?  I've done some experimenting, but haven't found it yet.  I've tried comparing with corresponding files from 13.04, but there are a lot of changes and I haven't been able to pin it down.

Comment: I don't believe this is anything changed in ubuntu-themes, it's a change in gnome/nautilus 3.8+. If you look closely you'll see the same in a nautilus window, doesn't quite matter as the background is off-white & text dark. As far as on the Desktop Gnome no longer uses or cares about that. So the fix may be more complicated than it seems.

Comment: After a bit more experimenting (I've played with everything in nautilus.css) I have to agree with you.  Also, the same problem occurs with other unrelated themes, e.g., Adwaita.  Is it worth trying to post a bug report with the nautilus project?

Comment: Oh, I just checked the Nautilus bugs on Launchpad and there it was, Bug #1236601.  It's been acknowledged.  Anyone else it affects should chime in.